# Sequelize asking for multiple values of association when explicitly defining foreign key

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am creating a model in sequelize as:

```
const Desk = sequelize.define('Desk', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    number: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['store_id', 'number'],
        message: 'A desk with same number exists on this store'
      }
    ],
    tableName: 'desk',
    underscored: true,
  });
```

I create an association as such:

```
Desk.belongsTo(models.Store, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'storeId',
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

I explicitly specify the name of the foreign key so that I can add it as an index.

The problem arises when I try to create a row as such:

```
const data = { number: 4, storeId: 1 };
await Desk.create(data);
```

The above code raises an exception that **StoreId cannot be null** even though I explicitly changed the foreign key to storeId. Even if I try changing the data to

```
const data = { number: 4, StoreId: 1 };
```

I get the error: **storeId cannot be null**

I don't understand if I making some mistake in creating the model but it should not be asking me for multiple values of same field.